# Voltage-controlled switch using op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, switches

The problem I'm trying to solve: I have a vehicle that has 3 wires for the tail/brake light. When the vehicle is on there is 12 V+ between the red and black wires and there is 7 V+ between the red and orange wires. When you hit the brakes the 7 V+ between the red and orange wires steps up to 10 V+.

So I need to create a circuit that will turn on a set of LED lights when the voltage goes above 9 V. Currently, my circuit consists of a voltage divider (changing 12 V down to 9 V), an LM324N op-amp, and an FQI50N06 MOSFET (schematic shows IRF540).

For some reason, on the op-amp, when there is no input, the output is on, when the non-inverting input is higher than the inverting input the output is on, and when the inverting input is higher than the non-inverting input the output is off.

So in my mind, this circuit is working, except when there is no input, then the output should be off.

EDIT:
Something that just popped into my head as soon as I posted this: I wonder if putting a diode on the output would prevent the output from being on when there is no input.

Please see the attached schematic:

[image: Voltage Controlled Switch using LM324N]

EDIT2:

[image: Voltage Controlled Switch using LM324N w/ 100K Resistors]

EDIT3:

[image: Voltage Controlled Switch using LM324N w/ 153K Resistor]

Comment: What do you mean by "no input"? There is nothing at all connected (open circuit)? The inputs are at 0V? Something else?

Comment: Correct, 0V.  If I completely disconnect the non-inverting input.  If the non-inverting input is 3v+, there's no output.

Comment: You shouldn't have an open circuit at the input(s), which I'm assuming is what you mean by "completely disconnect". Op amps have an input bias current (even if it's very small) and that current needs a path to flow.

Comment: So by Pin 3 being open, this is causing the current to essentially flow backwards through the LM324N?  Sorry, I'm new to OP-Amps.  This is my first project with one.

Comment: If you disconnect either input, it effectively goes to almost the supply rail. A 100K resistor from the input to ground will stop that.

Comment: No need to apologize. With an open circuit at the input the op amp isn't going to behave well because of the input bias current. I suggest tying a high-value resistor (e.g. 100k) from the + input to GND, and another high-value resistor from the - input to the 12V supply. This will turn the output off when your normal inputs are disconnected.

Comment: So the second schematic in the above post should be the solution theoretically then correct?

Comment: Yes, that should work. The input bias currents are very small (100nA max for this op amp) so even with high-value resistors there is very little voltage drop across them when the normal inputs are disconnected. So the + input is at GND, the - input at 12V, and the output is low (i.e. FET and LED off). When the inputs are connected, they just need to supply a little extra current to apply a voltage across the resistors you added.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, I'll give this a try this evening.  That makes perfect sense because I also now remember that as soon as I would put my meter on the input, it would turn the light out.  So just the added resistance of the the meter was enough to achieve this.

Comment: Good luck. If you confirm that it works properly, please come back and either (a) post an answer with the updated circuit and accept it or (b) post a comment with "@Null" to notify me and I'll post an answer. This will allow the system to mark the question as answered (it doesn't know that the question was answered in the comments). Please take a look at the [help] if you have any questions, and welcome to the site!

Comment: You LED lights wont get anywhere 12 V due to opamp output swing and gatesource volts needed to drive the FET .consider a P channel design ,it will be cheap because your currents are not high .

Comment: So I played around more with the circuit last nights and came up with EDIT3 based on your suggestions.  If I used 2 150K resistors in the circuit as showed in Edit2, the light would not work, by using just one, the light seemed to work correctly.  The light that Ia am using is a Version 3 36" Rear Light Bar from RLBStore.com (http://www.rlbstore.com/store/blue-strobes/).  The tail lights and Brake lights are the same LED and all of the circuitry is internal for the bar, except this circuit I'm trying to develop. Still concerned it won't work when tested on the car, which is 600 miles away.

Comment: I still need to verify voltages going to the light through the MOSFET.  Even though the circuit "works", I want to make sure it's working correctly.

Comment: @Null The way I am getting my reference voltage of 9v is through an L7809. Does anyone see any problems with that? Essentially, if the Orange wire is below 9v, the brake is off. If the Orange wire is above 9v, the brake is on.

Comment: The - input should be fine with the L7809 providing the input. However, is the + input connected directly to 12V? If so, that violates the input common mode range of the LM324 (which requires the inputs to be at least 1.5V below the supply voltage, which is 12V here). You'll want to limit that input to no more than 10.5V.

Comment: Thanks @NULL. Good to know. Now I have an issue of regulating 10.5V. I don't think a simple voltage divider will work considering the charging system fluctuates. The input would be anywhere from 12V-14.4V.

Comment: Is the "Brake 12V" input the same supply as the +12V supply? If not, you might be able to divide down both input sources by the same factor to keep the op amp inputs within the common mode range. Either way, if you can use a different op amp I would suggest something with rail-to-rail inputs. Also, if you're just comparing the inputs a [comparator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator) is more suitable than an op amp. For example, the [TLV3701](http://www.ti.com/product/tlv3701) is rail-to-rail input and accepts supplies up to 16V.

Comment: @NULL, what about an [LM339](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm339.pdf)?  Also, would the schematic essentially be the same aside from pin placement?

The issue is that when the brake is pressed, it appears to only go up to 10.5V from 7V I believe.  I'll have to go back and look at my notes.  But I don't want limitations if I can avoid them.

Comment: That isn't rail-to-rail. It would be advertised as such if it was, and you can confirm with the datasheet (look for the \$V_{\text{ICR}}\$ spec -- it also requires its inputs to be 1.5V below the positive rail). Also, that's a quad comparator -- do you need four comparators in one chip? The schematic is essentially identical with a comparator vs. an op amp. An op amp would work here, too, it's just that you're simply comparing two input voltages (exactly what a comparator does) and I think you're more likely to find a comparator with rail-to-rail input.

Comment: @NULL, ok, I'll look around and see what I can dig up.  No, I don't need a quad, it was just what I originally ordered, so it's what got used.  Ideally a smaller chip would work better.  I'll update when I get the new parts or I verify I'm withing 1.5V.  Thanks.

Comment: If the brake voltage only actually goes up to 10.5V you're okay with either the LM324 or LM339 -- that's 1.5V below the 12V rail. It's just that your schematic seems to imply that the + input can be connected to 12V. What wires are actually connected to which pins? I would guess black = GND and red = 12V, but what about orange? And what's that "Brake +3V" input?

Comment: @NULL, when back over my notes, the brake does go up to charging voltage (we'll call this 12V for sake of argument).  So that said, if my brake goes to 12V, I'm out of spec for the LM324 correct?  I'm not fully understanding the 1.5V and  VICR.  On a side note, I found an [LM311](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm311.pdf), it appears to me that VICR is 13V.  I still didn't see Rail-to-Rail though.

Comment: @NULL, Also, if the brake goes to 12V and the Supply is 12V, then I can theoretically create a voltage divider, correct?  I just need to make sure that the reference voltage is over 7 volts.

Comment: 12V brake with a 12V supply would be out of spec for the LM324, yes. To read the \$V_{\text{ICR}}\$, note the supply voltage at the top of the datasheet table. For the LM311, it is specifying for \$\pm 15\$V supplies. So a min \$V_{\text{ICR}}\$ of 13V means the input must be at no higher than 13V (i.e. 2V below the supply voltage).

Comment: Yes, you can use a voltage divider on the 12V input. If needed, you can also divide down the reference voltage to make sure it is between the two expected voltage levels (when the brake is on vs. off).

Comment: @NULL, so if I made my reference voltage 10.5V and my positive between 10.V and 12V I would then be in spec with the LM324, correct?

Comment: Mmm, no, you're too close to the positive rail (12V). You need to divide both inputs *down*. Stick a 2:1 voltage divider at each input. I'm still not clear on what is actually connected to the inputs. **Which wire (red, black, orange) is connected to which pins? What is the meaning of the "Brake +3V", "Brake +12V", and "+9V" inputs? Are they actually 3V, 12V, and 9V, respectively?**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29789/discussion-on-question-by-jrichardson-voltage-controlled-switch-using-opamp).

Answer (score 1):

*Note: this circuit is based on the ongoing discussion in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29789/discussion-on-question-by-jrichardson-voltage-controlled-switch-using-opamp). I'm posting this to save a schematic which can be simulated on-site. The circuit can/will be modified pending further information. Resistor values are roughly chosen to simply provide proof-of-concept.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fW4mUc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>